# What are the basic assumed endpoints with ActiveResource?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, rest, jersey, activeresource

I have a java backed web service that i want to test out with ActiveResource.

What are the base assumed url endpoints, say I have a resource for Users.

Currently my url is:

```
localhost:8080/api/users
```

I created a test class, and it fails because it assumes I have this url:

```
localhost:8080/api/users.json
```

I was planning on doing this:

```
localhost:8080/api/users/   (GET - lists users)
localhost:8080/api/users/create (POST - create a user)
localhost:8080/api/users/10  (GET user with id 10)
localhost:8080/api/users/10/update (POST - update user with id 10)
```

What is the Rails standard?  Is this standard the 'standard' across other frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails (and therefore ActiveResource) assume that for every resource (users, posts...) you have  available the following endpoints (I excluded the endpoint prefix):

- GET `/users.json` to get all of the users
- GET `/users/2.json` to get details about user with ID = 2
- POST `/users.json` to create a new user
- DELETE `/users/2.json` to delete user with ID = 2
- PUT `/users/2.json` to update user with ID = 2

You can choose the data format like this:

```
User.format = :xml
User.find(2) # => GET /users/2.xml
```

It would probably be best if you create a new Rails app, scaffold the user resource and play with it from console. That way you could also see the data expected data structure.

Comment: ok got it, so each url should support both .xml and .json also.

Comment: If you want to. There's nothing wrong with supporting just the json format (it's the default).